# Running an Rscript on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, r

I have a BATCH File script on a Windows machine that consists of the following line:

```
c:\R\bin\Rscript.exe "c:\Users\user\Documents\Shares.R"
```

I want to do the same thing but using Mac OS X at the moment I am using Automator => Run Shell Script and the following line:

```
open "/usr/bin/Rscript" "/Users/usr/Documents/Shares.R"
```

It opens R, finds the file and displays the R code. I want the R code contained in the script to run (like it does in Windows).

Any ideas?

Anthony.

Answer (score 8):

This will be enough :

```
/usr/bin/Rscript "/Users/usr/Documents/Shares.R"
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.x.x\bin\Rscript.exe
```

On Linux:

```
rwrapper.executable=/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript
```

On Mac:

```
/usr/bin/Rscript "/Users/usr/Documents/Shares.R"
```